# oninput gets triggered while focusing on input field in internet explorer(Version 11.1082.18362.0)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Below is HTML I ran on IE11(Version 11.1082.18362.0) and Chrome(Version 88.0.4324.104). 
If the placeholder is not used, oninput is working fine in both the browsers, but when it is used while focusing on the input field in the IE, the oninput gets triggered which is not desirable. How to fix that ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="new" oninput="alert('input')" onchange="alert('change')" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean oninput is triggered in IE if we click on the field but only if it has a placeholder?

Comment: precisely, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue of IE. `<textarea>` element also has this issue in IE. You can use the following code as a workaround to fix it in IE 11:

```js
function onInputWraper(cb) {
  if (!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/)) return cb;


  return function(e) {
    var t = e.target,
      active = (t == document.activeElement);
    if (!active || (t.placeholder && t.composition_started !== true)) {
      t.composition_started = active;
      if ((!active && t.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') || t.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
    cb(e);
  };
}

var el = document.getElementById('test');
el.addEventListener("input", onInputWraper(myFunction), true);

function myFunction() {
  alert("input");
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" value="" placeholder="new" onchange="alert('change')" />
```

Comment: can you please, elaborate what exactly is happening here?